# Does any harmonic function on the punctured disc have an extension to the entire unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

The solution to the Dirichlet Problem in a disc should give an extension to arbitrarily large discs centred at the origin, with radius less than 1.

Comment: There is a contradiction between the title and the text. Could you elaborate what background you have in mind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for example $\ln |x|$ in $\mathbb R^2\setminus \{ 0\}.$